# Чем отличается operator.itemgetter от operator.getitem?

Tags: python

Писал вот такой код

```
import operator

tuples = [(1, 'd'), (2, 'b'), (4, 'a'), (3, 'c')] 

print(sorted(tuples, key=operator.itemgetter(1)))
```

В процессе написания опечатался и вместо `.itemgetter` написал `.getitem`, в итоге было вот это -

```
import operator

tuples = [(1, 'd'), (2, 'b'), (4, 'a'), (3, 'c')] 

print(sorted(tuples, key=operator.getitem(1)))
```

с которым код не сработал и выдал вот такую ошибку

```
TypeError: getitem expected 2 arguments, got 1
```

В документации ничего подробного нет. Поэтому решил спросить здесь у понимающих разницу между первым и вторым

P.S. Первый вариант кода рабочий

Comment: вот здесь почитайте про то и то - https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html

Comment: "В документации ничего подробного нет" - прямо вот интересно, что за документацию вы читали, где этого ничего нет? )

Comment: Ничего подробного* 
Про метод gititem сказано только "Return the value of a at index b."
Больше никаких пояснений. С чем применять и прочее. Поэтому не совсем понятно

Comment: Ну просто не здесь это нужно применять. Этой функции нужно давать сразу давать конкретное `a`, а в функции, которая указывается для `key=` естественно сразу нельзя указывать от чего брать элемент по индексу, ведь эта функция будет применяться к элементам сортируемой коллекции.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`operator.getitem(lst, i)` - это то же самое, что и `lst[i]`:

```py
>>> import operator
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> lst[2]
3
>>> operator.getitem(lst, 2)
3
```